# In WPF: Set ValidatesOnDataErrors = true programmatically

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, c#-4.0, textbox, custom-controls

Is there any way to set ValidatesOnDataErrors=True programmatically?

I have a custome textbox Class that inheritates from Textbox like this:

```
public class ActiveTextBox:TextBox
    {
      public ActiveTextBox(){}
    }
```

I want to have a default ValidatesOnDataErrors to true on every instance of this textBox

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the TextProperty for the TextBox?
See [this](http://www.netframeworkdev.com/windows-presentation-foundation-wpf/set-validatesondataerrors-for-all-bindings-programmatically-24837.shtml) post.

One way is to create your own inherited binding.

```
public class ValidationBinding : Binding
{
    public ValidationBinding()
        : base()
    {
        this.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
    }
    public ValidationBinding(string path)
        : base(path)
    {
        this.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
    }
}
```

And in xaml

```
<my:ActiveTextBox Text="{l:ValidationBinding MyProp}" />
```

There are some other good tips in that post as well if this one doesn't suit you.